# IndexPath in tablew view cell returned is wrong on click of a label in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, nsindexpath

I have a label inside a table view cell.

On click of the label I want to segue to another view controller after retrieving the correct `indexPath`.

I have added a `gestureRecognizer` to the label. On click of the label it returns the wrong `indexPath` , it does not return the index Path of the cell in which the label is.

How can I solve this problem . Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Following is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell

        cell.name.text = feeds[indexPath.row].name

        nameClicked()
        return cell
    }


 func nameClicked(){
        cell.name.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TrendViewController.handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))
        cell.name.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }


    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        var touchPoint = cell.name.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
        var clickedLabelIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)!

        nameFromView = feeds[clickedLabelIndexPath.row].name
        print("IndexPath at touch",clickedLabelIndexPath)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile") as! ProfileViewController

        vc.clickedLabelIndexPath = clickedLabelIndexPath
        vc.nameFromView = feeds[clickedLabelIndexPath.row].name

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `gesture`? Just push your `viewController` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Here you'll always get the correct index.

Comment: @A.S We never click a label its always a button.

Comment: The issue is that you're using `cell` for the calculations, while `cell` is being reset to last dequeued row (avoid using it outside of `cellForRowAt:`). Instead of `cell.name.convert..` use `gestureRecognizer.locationInView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declare `cell` as instance property in your class,so you are adding gesture to the same cell's label. So create new cell using `dequeueReusableCell` and changed your method `nameClicked` by adding argument of type cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //create new cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
    cell.name.text = feeds[indexPath.row].name
    nameClicked(cell)
    return cell
}

func nameClicked(_ cell: TableCell){
    cell.name.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TrendViewController.handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))
    cell.name.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

Now change your `handleTap` method like this to get the correct `indexPath`.

```
func handleTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = self.tableView.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: gestureRecognizer.view!)
    if let indexPath = self. tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {
        print("\(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row)")
        //Add your code here
    }
}
```

**Note:** If your cell having only single cell then it is batter if you use `didSelectRowAt` method instead of adding gesture to label.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: @A.S Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make condition for check if cell is touched ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
   if cell.isTouched { 
      cell.setTouched
   }
   else { 
      cell.setNoTouched
   }

   return cell
}
```